# Getting an SDK Error with new .NET Core 2.2 Web API

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm getting an on the creation of a new Web API project in Visual Studio.  I used the Visual Studio ASP.NET Core Web App->Web Api project template:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.  
Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2. CMS.Api
```

There is a NuGet Dependency for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design (2.2.0) display in the solution explorer.

Environment:

```
Windows 10 1809
Visual Studio 2017 15.9.11

C:\Source>dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.203
 Commit:    e5bab63eca

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   c:\program files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.203\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.4
  Commit:  f95848e524

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  1.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  1.1.11 [c:\program files\dotnet\sdk]
  1.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  1.1.13 [c:\program files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.104 [c:\program files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [c:\program files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.503 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.503 [c:\program files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.505 [c:\program files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.203 [c:\program files\dotnet\sdk]


PS C:\Source> Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\' |  Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name Release | Foreach-Object { $_ -ge 461814 }
True
```

I looked at the following: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/11/18/how-to-target-net-core-2-2/

CMS.Api.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I created a global.json in the root of the project's folder:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.203"
  }
}
```

But any time I try to do a NuGet package restore, I keep getting the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/108

Comment: Thanks, I reinstalled 2.2.1 and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Please check,

1. You have installed ".NET Core 2.2" SDK x64 or x86 version. If not you can download it from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks
2. Make sure "2.2.110" folder is generated under below folder structure.

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk